# Transform Feedback: Could outputs be optimized away?

Tags: opengl, glsl

Without feedback, the optimizer might remove outputs from the last vertex processing shader if the fragment shader has no use for them.

Transform Feedback captures those outputs. It it possible that I won't capture all outputs because of this?

Or to phrase it differently, do I have to provide a fragment shader that does something with those values even if I will use the program exclusively to fill a feedback buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of the output variables to capture must be specified either in the shader itself with layout parameters or before program linking with `glTransformFeedbackVaryings​`. The GPU can use the list of captured variables as a blacklist for variables to optimize away.

So no, if you properly set up transform feedback, the optimizer won't break your shader.